# Missing of info symbol in whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-j7

I lost the info symbol in whatsapp, but the info option is there in the upper three dots menu. I don't know what is the reason. How can I regain it?

My phone is samsung galaxy J7 nxt.

Below is a screenshot of where the option used to be:[image]

Comment: I edited your question to make it clear what you're talking about. You can revert or edit in case I got it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp has changed the location of the option in it's latest update. That's not an issue, it's just a little change to the design. All you have to do, is press on a message that was written by you, and press on the three dots on the top right of the page.

[image]

If however you'd like to get the option back, the only way to do that would be by downloading an older version of whatsapp from [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/whatsapp-inc/).

You can also leave them feedback letting them know that you'd like the option moved back. To leave them feedback, open WhatsApp settings → help → contact us.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp has made several recent amendments in its interface. Though these are not big ones. So there is absolutely nothing to worry about it.

Another change that WhatsApp has made is with the Online Status Check. Previously, a couple of weeks ago whenever we open messenger to message a person say XYZ, we could clearly see the line "*Last Seen at sometime*.
But now we can only see the time.